# AS3 packages and folder locations

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, actionscript, package

I'm getting this error that says that my package is name doesn't reflect the location of my file. What do I need to do to fix this? I've googled, changed the name of my file, added classpaths. Please provide detailed instructions. I'm having trouble with this.

**Code:**

```
package CMA10{

  //Classes and stuff in here

}
```

**Error:** (Includes directory information)

> /Users/Moshe/Dropbox/Development/AIR/Projects/CMA10/campCD.as, Line 1  5001: The name of package 'CMA10' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the package definition's name inside this file, or move the file. /Users/Moshe/Dropbox/Development/AIR/Projects/CMA10/campCD.as

Comment: What's the name of your document class? What is your IDE, your dev environment? Is campCD.as your document class? Are there any classes outside your CMA10 folder? We need more info!

Comment: i'm assuming your .fla is in the folder named "CMA10", that campCD.as is your document class and that both your .fla and your campCD.as document class are in the same folder.  if so, you just write package{...//code...} instead of package CMA10{...//code...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your package looks like:

```
com.motion.util
```

The util.as containing the `util class` file should be located inside: `root of your flash file/com/motion/util.as`

Comment: Where does my document class go?

Comment: your document class can be anywhere you want, just like any other classes, but it's usually placed in the same location as your .fla.  as per jdecuyper's example, if your document class is util.as, you write "com.motion.util" in the document class field of your .fla properties

Comment: @TheDarkLnl1978 - I tried that, it didn't work. I think it needs to be in the same directory as the fla file and have NO package.

Answer (score 1):

A classes package needs to be identical to the folder structure that you have the class in and if the top folders location is not the same location as the .fla, a class path needs to be set in the .fla's Actionscript settings to point to the location of that top folder.

Class:

```
package
{
   public class ClassName
}
```

Import:

```
import ClassName;
```

Document Class:
ClassName

This class is in the same directory as the .fla that needs to use it or a class path pointing to the folder containing this class has to be setup in the Actionscript settings of the .fla.

Class:

```
package com.something.utils
{
   public class ClassName
}
```

Import:

```
import com.something.utils.ClassName;
```

Document Class:
com.something.utils.ClassName

This class must be located in "com\something\utils" folder. The "com" folder must be located in the same directory as the .fla that needs to use it or a class path pointing to the folder containing the "com" folder has to be setup in the Actionscript settings of the .fla.